# BrokenPipeError when installing python modules via pip using blender's python

Tags: python

I am using Blender 2.9 (and its corresponding python 3.9) on MacOS (BigSur 11.4). I want to use pip to install scipy so that I can use it within Blender either in the console or running a script. When I try to use or upgrade Blender's pip, I get a broken pipe error.

I run:

`bin/python3.9 lib/python3.9/ensurepip`

and my output is:

```
ERROR: Pipe to stdout was broken
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Frustratingly, when I try to run:

`bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I get the same thing plus this message telling me to upgrade using the command that just failed.

```
ERROR: Pipe to stdout was broken
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.93/python/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The only thing I found was this [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4170) where a user of pip encountered the same error when using `pip list | head` which they seemed to have fixed, and makes sense because they explicitly used the pipe. When I am using pip in this case, I don't know what exactly is calling pipe so I don't know where the error is really coming from.

Comment: https://linuxpip.org/broken-pipe-python-error/ may be helpful

Comment: thank you I'll check this out

Comment: Hello, can you make sure you are using Blender version 2.93 or up ? Versions 2.90, 2.91 and 2.92 are NOT compatible with python 3.9, but they are with python 3.7

Comment: yes, I am using 2.93.2

Answer (score 1):

It was an encoding problem in my terminal (bash in mac's Terminal app). For some reason invoking blender's version of python wasn't fully functional. It wouldn't even return ensurepip's version or do basic math operations:

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.93/python/bin/python3.9
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 16 2021, 14:53:03) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ensurepip
>>> ensurepip.version()
>>> print(ensurepip.version())
>>> 
>>> v=ensurepip.version()
>>> v
>>> print(v)
>>> type(v)
>>> 
>>> 3+6
>>> 
>>> exit()
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I have no idea why, but doing the same commands in [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) worked fine and I was able to successfully install scipy.